# C++ перегрузка оператора "+" и метод push

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов

Всем привет. Я изучаю классы и перегрузки операций в С++. В общем дали мне тут задание создать некое подобие из STL библиотеки контейнер set. Он у меня сделан, но не совсем правильно работает метод push и перегрузка операции "+". То есть к примеру X + Y. Я закидываю во временный массив Х потом У и после этого я должен их отсортировать и вызвать метод удаления уникальных элементов. Но прежде чем это реализовать, хотелось бы разобраться в чем причина не работы метода push и перегрузки "+". При сложении у меня выдается ошибка, а при использовании push выводится только первая буква. Я думал использовать string или vector'а но потом решил все такие остановится на том что я сделал. Заранее благодарю.

Вот мой код:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;

   class Set
   {
       private:
          char *num;size_t size;
       public:
          int min();
          void sort();
          void unique();
          bool find();
          Set(){}
          Set(char *str)
          {
              size = strlen(str);
              num = new char[size];
              for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
              {
                  num[i] = str[i];
              }
              //sort();
              //unique();
          }
          const Set& push(char *str)
          {
             char *temp = new char[size+strlen(str)];
             for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
             {
                  temp[i] = num[i];
             }
             temp[size] = *str;
             delete [] num;
             this->num = temp;
             this->size += strlen(str);
             return *this;
          }

          const Set operator+(const Set& s)
          {
             if(this->size != s.size)
             {
                 return NULL;
             }
             Set v;
             size = v.size + size;
             for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
             {
                 v.num[i] = num[i] + s.num[i];
             }
             return v;
          }
          friend const ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Set& s);
    };

const ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Set& s)
{
    for(int i=0; i<s.size; i++)
    {
        os << s.num[i];
    }
    return os;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    char s[25] = "Hello world ";
    Set ss(s);
    char q[25] = "Hola\n";
    ss.push(q);
    Set sw(q);
    ss = ss + sw;
    cout << ss;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> а при использовании push выводится только первая буква.

Ну так вы в `push` как раз и копируете только первую букву

```
         for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
         {
              temp[i] = num[i];
         }
         temp[size] = *str;
```

содержимое `num[]` вы копируете в `temp[]` целиком - при помощи цикла. А куда девался цикл для `str`? Почему вы для `str` не написали такого же цикла?

Вот это

```
         temp[size] = *str;
```

это копирование только первой буквы.

Comment: я изменил добавил цикл но выводит только то что я занёс push'ем. А предыдущее не выводит.

Comment: @Lado: Нам отсюда не видно, что вы там добавили.

Comment: я добавил свой ответ. Там то, что я изменил, как раз тот самый цикл.

Answer (score 0):

строчка за строчкой:

```
 const Set operator+(const Set& s)
          {
             if(this->size != s.size)
             {
                 return NULL;
             }
```

во первых возвращая const Set вы сами создаете неудобство для пользователья.
Возвращайте просто Set.
Во вторых вы вместо Set возвращаете Null, если размеры множеств не равны?.. и что это означает?... У вас в main() размеры множеств, которые вы суммируете, не равны...
пойдем дальше:

```
 Set v;
   size = v.size + size;
   for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
       {
         v.num[i] = num[i] + s.num[i];
       }
```

вы определили конструктор по умолчанию с пустым телом, потому у вашего обьекта v данные неинициализированы, но вы его используете, а потом возвращаете, так что у вас ошибка не одна. И потом один маленький совет не по вопросу: старайтесь меньше использовать постинкремент (i++ каждый раз создает временный обьект), особенно в циклах...

Comment: да, вы правы сравнение здесь не уместно. Но по поводу сложения я не совсем понял. Ведь я в main() создаю еще один объект и получается потом складываю два объекта, а так как у меня строки то должно выйти как некое объединение. Но я не совсем понял где ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

То, что тут за класс set не подходит к описанию контейнера set а подходит к описанию vector.

http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set
Поиск, удаление и вставка операции имеют логарифмическую сложность.
Наборы обычно реализуется как красно-черные деревья.

Действия над вектором как над множеством можно сделать через:

```
#include <algorithm>
```

А это неправильно:

```
Set(){}
```

должно быть:

```
Set(){num=nullptr;}
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем я тут вот так вот исправил и все заработало. Возможно есть варианты это улучшить буду рад если поделитесь.

```
     const Set& push(char *str)
     {
        char *temp = new char[size+strlen(str)+1];
        //char sum;
//        for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
//        {
//            temp[i] = num[i];
//            //sum += str[i];
//            temp[i] = str[i];
//        }
        strcat(temp, num);
        strcat(temp, str);
        //puts(temp);
        //temp[size] = sum;
        delete [] num;
        this->num = temp;
        this->size += strlen(str);
        return *this;
    }
```

Comment: Что-то не похоже на нормальный вариант. Зачем один и тот же кусок кода дважды? Почему удаление закомментировано? И вообще, где описание, что было неправильно?

Comment: @Qwertiy У меня до этого выводилась только одна буква(символ). Сейчас уже нет, но при этом когда я что-либо заношу push'ем (это мой метод) то выводится только занесенное но при этом старое исчезает.

Comment: Нет, не заработало. Ошибки по-прежнему грубейшие. Во-первых, делать strcat в неинициализированный массив нельзя. Во-вторых ваш класс был изначально заточен на то, что в нем хранятся НЕ нуль-терминированные массивы. А здесь вдруг вы перешли на нуль-терминированные строки. Вы уж определитесь сначала, что именно вы будете хранить.

Comment: @AnT хорошо а как тогда сделать правильно? Потому что я Вас не совсем понимаю. Как я помню для нуль-терминированной строки используются функции strtok, strcpy, strlen. Но по поводу strcat я не видел.

Comment: @Lado: Перед тем как говорить о "как сделать правильно" надо решить *что именно* надо сделать. Вы нам пока не объясняли, что именно вы пытаетесь сделать и почему это все называется `Set`. Пока не ясно, *что именно* надо сделать, никакого "правильно" или "неправильно" быть не может.